# Starting activity immediatly at boot using direct boot mode

Tags: android, android-activity, boot

When starting an activity at boot using boot_completed, it can take some times for the activity to start at boot. Would it be possible to start the activity immediatly at boot using direct boot mode?

Comment: When _BOOT_COMPLETED_ receiver registered and call _onReceive()_ method at that time activity will be launched

Comment: Yes i know. But there is always a delay between the moment the device has started and the activity started when registering a receiver with boot_completed

Comment: Of course, it will take time for your app to receive broadcast, the system prioritizes its process/apps than your app. You can check this by yourself by capturing a log with no filter on.

Comment: So cant i do it with direct boot mode?

Answer (score 1):

See [android:priority](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element)

> It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)

Default value is 0 according to the document

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Edit: Create an Accessibility Service. Make sure your app is enabled on Accessibility Settings and your service is running, your service will automatically launch at startup. Launch your services or your activity inside this method in your Accessibility service

```
 @Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
}
```

I just tried it and it looks realy promising! A lot faster than BOOT_COMPLETED receiver. Let me know if its works!

Note: Google might not approve your app though.

See : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility

> Although it's beneficial to add accessibility features in your app, you should use them only for the purpose of helping users with disabilities interact with your app.

Comment: Even with a priority i still jave delay between startup and the receiver receiving the message